# Как проверить на наличие записи в БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Нужно перед добавления пользователя в базу данных проверить на уникальность логин пользователя. Код работает, но как заносил пользователей с одинаковыми логинами, так и продолжает это делать. В чем ошибка?

```php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass1 = filter_var(trim($_POST['password1']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass2 = filter_var(trim($_POST['password2']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($pass1 != $pass2) {
        echo "Пароли не совпадают";
    }

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','popkornimage');

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT `login` FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '$login'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует";
    } else {
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `user`(`login`, `password`) VALUE('$login', '$pass2')");
    $mysql->close();

    header("Location: /");
    }
```

Comment: как думаете, что будет если при проверке укажут логин вида `' or 1=1` ?

Comment: и в целом надо задуматься, вот ввел вам пользователь пароль, а вы раз так его и изменили, сохранили в базу и он теперь зная свой логин и пароль авторизоваться не может, потому что вы решили обрезать пробелы и скобки из него.

Comment: @teran Да вроде у меня работает авторизация. Только что проверил, все нормально

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `mysqli_query` на `$mysql->query` и `mysqli_num_rows` на `$mysql->num_rows`.

Comment: Ставлю этому вопросу минус, поскольку принятый ответ бессмысленный и вредный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, проблема в строчке

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `login` FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
```

Тут у вас каждый раз подставляется "$login" вместо значения переменной, а так как такого пользователя в базе данных нет, она каждый раз возвращает 0 результатов.

Исправить можно добавить конкатенацию в строку запроса:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT `login` FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '". $login . "'");
```

Но это не самое лучшее решение. Для того что бы обеспечить максимальную безопасность и удобство в разработке лучше всего использовать ОРМ такие, как [Doctrine ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html), или [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent),они предоставляют объектно ориентированный интерфейс для работы с базами данных. И предоставляют много вспомогательных функций.

Comment: Ладно, я понимаю, новичок не понимает как работают строки в пхп. Но у кого рука поднялась плюсик этому ответу поставить?

Comment: Я думаю что там проблема не в том что парень не понимают как, работают строки, а скорее в том что запутался в скобках. Можете дополнить мой ответ объяснениями про строки, лишним не будет, думаю многим поможет.

Comment: *в двух скобках*? Вы это сейчас серьёзно тут пишете? Что запутались в двух скобках и поэтому написали бессмысленный ответ? Этот ответ невозможно "дополнить". Невозможно дополнить ответ, который решает **несуществующую** проблему и является на 100% бессмысленным.

Comment: Я сужу по себе, когда я начинал делать свои первые скрипты на PHP я путался в скобках именно в запросах в бд, так как сам запрос в скобках строки и так же одинарными скобками нужно выделять строки в SQL запросе. Подумал что человеку поможет то что помогло мне. Вы всегда можете ответить по своему.

Comment: 1. символы `"` и `'` называются **кавычки**, а не скобки. 2. Ты в них путаешься до сих пор. Твой ответ не поможет вообще никому, поскольку два фрагмента кода в нем делают одно и то же. Что делает ответ заведомо бессмысленным.

Comment: Сказал бы сразу что фрагменты одно и то же делают, а то тебя никто не понял. Похоже так и есть, я не проверил когда, отвечал, наверное мой ответ случайно выбрали правильным, нужно отвечать еще.